# Finding Missing HTML

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

When I look at the html code in my browser, I am seeing the following below (minus the stars in rows 3 and 4).  But when I scrape the data, and print the html in scrapy shell, the *** out rows are not there.  Why is this?  Also, how would I get the text for colspan = "2"?  Thanks. I have been trying the following:

```
response.xpath('//table[@id="playertable_0"]/tbody/tr/th[@colspan="2"]//text()')
```

The actual url I am using is: http://games.espn.com/ffl/leaders?&scoringPeriodId=1&seasonId=2018.  To get the html below, I am running this code:

```
table = response.xpath('//table[@id="playertable_0"]')
table.css('tr.playerTableBgRowHead.tableHead.playertableSectionHeader').extract()


    <tr class="playerTableBgRowHead tableHead playertableSectionHeader">
        <th colspan="1" class="playertableSectionHeaderFirst">OFFENSIVE PLAYERS</th>
        ***<td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td>***
        ***<th colspan = "2" > WK 1 </th> == $0***
        <td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td>
        <th colspan="4">PASSING</th>
        <td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td>
        <th colspan="3">RUSHING</th>
        <td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td>
        <th colspan="4">RECEIVING</th>
        <td class="sectionLeadingSpacer"></td>
        <th colspan="3">MISC</th><td class="sectionLeadingSpacer">
        </td><th colspan="1">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>'
```

Comment: Likely being injected through javascript, such as jquery or any of the libraries that do that.

Comment: How would i go about getting the data then?

Comment: First check the answer by kasun and see if that helps. But do note that if content is being added asynchronously using javascript, you have no other option than to execute that javascript, webscraping in 2018 is a completely different ballgame than it used to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the `<tr>` or `<th>` tags that are injected through JS. It is the `<tbody>`. So the Following xpath works.

`response.xpath('//table[@id="playertable_0"]//tr/th[@colspan="2"]//text()')`

Viewing the source from the browser will tell you what is injected from JS and what is returned as HTML.

see `view-source:http://games.espn.com/ffl/leaders?&scoringPeriodId=1&seasonId=2018` in chrome.